# What does it mean when the first "for" parameter is blank?

Tags: c++, syntax, for-loop

I have been looking through some code and I have seen several examples where the first element of a for cycle is omitted.

An example:

```
for ( ; hole*2 <= currentSize; hole = child)
```

What does this mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It just means that the user chose not to set a variable to their own starting value.

```
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
```

is equivalent to...

```
int i = 0;
for( ; i < x; i++)
```

EDIT (in response to comments): These aren't exactly equivalent.  the scope of the variable i is different.

Sometimes the latter is used to break up the code.  You can also drop out the third statement if your indexing variable is modified within the for loop itself...

```
int i = 0;
for(; i < x;)
{
...
i++
...
}
```

And if you drop out the second statement then you have an infinite loop.

```
for(;;)
{
runs indefinitely
}
```

Comment: Declaring i inside the for loop pre-initialization isn't *quite* equivalent to declaring it just before the loop.  In the former case, its scope is the body of the for statement -- i.e., you can't access it after the for statement's body closes.  In the latter case, the variable i can still be accessed after the for loop body.

Comment: While you *can* use `for(;i<x;)`, it's stylistically better to go with the smipler and easier-to-read `while(i<x)`.

Comment: Actually those aren't equivalent. "i" is declared only for that scope when declared in the for keyword.

Comment: I also like to go with smipler code.  Also, it should be as Redditable as possible. :)

Comment: Actually, you don't need to set any variable in the first expression of a `for` statement.  Try this: `for (std::cout<<"first\n"; false;);`.  As Edward said in his comment, it is a pre-initialization step.

Comment: why this code gives error: type 'int' unexpected and 'j' undeclared identifier  
 for (int i = 0, int j = arrSize - 1; i < j; )     i just want to omit the loop-expression part

Comment: @lsrawat You should probably ask a new question but it is `int i = 0, j = arrSize - 1` and not `int i = 0, int j = arrSize - 1`

Answer (score 8):

The `for` construct is basically `( pre-loop initialisation; loop termination test; end of loop iteration)`, so this just means there is no initialisation of anything in this for loop.

You could refactor any `for` loop thusly:

```
pre-loop initialisation
while (loop termination test) {
...
end of loop iteration
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some people have been getting it wrong so I just wanted to clear it up.

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < 10; i++)
```

is not the same as

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Variables declared inside the for keyword are only valid in that scope.

To put it simply.

**Valid ("i" was declared outside of the loops scope)**

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < 10; i++)
{
  //Code
}
std::cout << i;
```

**InValid ("i" does not exist outside the loop scope)**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  //Code
}
std::cout << i;
```

Answer (score 2):

It means that the initial value of `hole` was set before we got to the loop

Answer (score 1):

That means loop control variable is initialized before the for loop .

```
For C  code,

int i=0;
for( ; i <10 ; i++) { } //since it does not allow variable declaration in loop 

For C++  code,

for(int i=0 ; i <10 ; i++) { }
```

Comment: C99 allows you to use the "C++" form, so it is no longer necessary to declare the variable outside the for statement. However, in both C and C++, a variable declared inside the for statement goes out of scope after that statement. If you want to use the variable after the for statement is finished, the for(;i<10;i++) syntax is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could omit any of the parameters of a for loop.
ie: for(;;) {} is about the same as while(true) {}

Answer (score 1):

It means that the initial value of `hole` was set before we got to the loop.

Looks like a list traversal of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you wanted to

```
for (hole=1 ; hole*2 <= currentSize; hole = child)
```

But the value of hole just before the for loop was already 1, then you can slip this initilization part of the loop:

```
/* value of hole now is 1.*/
for ( ; hole*2 <= currentSize; hole = child)
```