# What it does when we write for(;;) ? What does the double semicolon in the for loop does?

Tags: c++, for-loop

And also only one semi colon inside the for loop in the given code?
Without closing the loop it writes another statement with scope resolution. I would be very thankful if you answer my queries.

```
class D : public A,B,C
{
    int val;
    public:

        D()
        {
            val=1;
        }


        void update_val(int new_val)
        {
            for(;new_val%2==0;new_val/=2)A::func(val);
            for(;new_val%3==0;new_val/=3)B::func(val);
            for(;new_val%5==0;new_val/=5)C::func(val);
        }

        void check(int); 
};
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1971326/10377254) answer your problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean when the first "for" parameter is blank?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971311/what-does-it-mean-when-the-first-for-parameter-is-blank)

Answer (score 2):

> What does the double semicolon in the for loop does?

`for` statement has this syntax:

```
for( initialization ; condition ; increment ) body;
```

Any part can be ommited but you must keep semicolon. So when you write:

```
for(;;) body;
```

it means that all three parts are omitted, but required by syntax semicolons are still there.

> What it does when we write for(;;) ?

It is equal to:

```
while( true )
```

In this statement:

```
for(;new_val%2==0;new_val/=2)A::func(val);
```

only first part - the initialization is skipped, but semicolon is still there.

Note that since C++11 there is another syntax is available - for range loop when instead of 2 semicolons you have only one colon:

```
for( int i : int_array ) do_something( i );
```